# A question about a pause in an itemize environment inside an enumerated environment

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

I have an itemize environment inside an enumerated environment (with item 1 and 2).

First, I want to show my two enumerated items: item 1 and item 2. After that, one pause. Finally, after the pause, go back to my first enumerated item and show my itemization (not enumerated) inside the item 1.

So, suppose my enumerated environment as:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item I want that the first enumerated item before the pause

   \item I want that the show the enumerated item before the pause
\end{enumerate}
```

Now, I want a pause and return to item 1 to show the itemized environment:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item I want that the first enumerated item before the pause
         \begin{itemize}
              \item My first item (not enumerated) after the pause
              \item My second item (not enumerated) after the pause
         \end{itemize}

   \item I want that the show the enumerated item before the pause
\end{enumerate}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beamer overlays to control when the `itemize` environment is shown:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item I want that the first enumerated item before the pause
           \begin{itemize}[<2->]
                \item My first item (not enumerated) after the pause
                \item My second item (not enumerated) after the pause
           \end{itemize}
  
     \item I want that the show the enumerated item before the pause
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```